# Оптимизация запроса с inner join самой первой записи

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

Всем привет, есть таблица "А"  которая содержит  +11тыс, и есть таблица "Б" которая содержит +400 миллионов записей, получается что таблица "Б" кол. записей / кол. записей "А" = на каждый внешний ключ таблицы "А"
Задача вытащить с лимитом от 10шт до 5000тыс штук из таблицы "А" с привязкой самой 1-ой записи  таблицы "Б", накидал запрос, но после 10 минут ожидания сбросил, так и не дождавшись окончания.

```
select "a".*, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from "a"
inner join b on b.col_table_a_id = a.id 
and b.id = (select min(id) from b where a.id = b.col_table_a_id)
limit 100 offset 0;
```

Есть идея создать в таблице "Б" поле first и установить туда значение в true у первой записи, но мне кажется это како-то костыль прям жесткий...

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: В таблице b добавлен составной индекс (`CREATE INDEX indx_b_col_table_a_id ON b (col_table_a_id, id);`)? У меня аналогичный join (в таблице b +13млн записей) отрабатывает за 200 мс.

Comment: партицирована таблица то хоть?

Comment: @teran нет, пробовал как-то сделать, отписал в одном чате по постгресу, сказали что нет в этом смысла, таблица очень маленькая

Comment: @MrFylypenko нету такого, есть col_table_a_id, datatime, id

Comment: маленькая это сколько гбайт ?

Comment: @Ricco381 добавьте составной индекс, обязательно в том порядке как указал. В подзапросе тогда не будет цикла, бд будет смотреть в индекс и итоговый запрос отработает быстро.

Comment: @teran размер конкретно этой 231 GB.

Comment: вроде не сказать что маленькая-то. поскольку структуру таблицы вы не описали и сценарии использования тоже, не ясно насколько ее полезно партицировать.

Comment: @teran в таблицу сохраняются данные каждые 5-10 минут, выше я писал что в нее сохраняются данные по связи из другой таблицы в которой около 12к записей, партицирование как я понял можно сделать либо по времени, я дел каждые 2 месяца либо по каждой системе, но тогда будет более 12 тысяч таблиц, но у меня даже при партицировании по датам почему-то ломалась база данных...

П.С. Данные в таблице все числовые, там около 8 столбцов вроде, ломалась после рестарта, просто не стартовала, а также до рестарта проверял скорость выборки и особого прироста не было

Comment: чтобы партицирование давало результат, условия запроса должны однозначно давать планировщику понять, с какими партициями требуется работать. Но тут познания у меня общие, ибо с указанной СУБД я  не работал.

Comment: @Ricco381 можно у таблицы `a` добавить колонку с первой записью из таблицы `b` и разово сделать update такой колонки. Всех кейсов не знаю, это самый минимум затрат как по мне, не знаю как часто будет выполняться указанный в вопросе запрос и добавляться значения в таблицу `a`

Comment: @MrFylypenko это какую колонку в таблицу А можно добавить из Б?)

Comment: @Ricco381 `id` из таблицы b. Имею ввиду, зачем постоянно вычислять main(b.id) в запросе, когда его можно хранить в таблице `a`, и не вычислять в последующем.

Comment: @MrFylypenko была такая идея, но сделать поле в таблице Б и поставить true у первой записи, но нашел вариант по лучше)

Answer (score 0):

А если как-то так попробовать, чтобы без подзапроса было, а просто ещё один `inner join` вместо этого:

```
select a.*, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from a
inner join 
(select min(b.id) min_b_id, a.id a_id from a
inner join b on b.col_table_a_id = a.id 
group by a.id) j on a.id = j.a_id
inner join b on b.col_table_a_id = j.a_id and b.id = j.min_b_id
limit 100 offset 0;
```

Я не настоящий сварщик, может это и хуже будет или вообще не то, но просто как вариант. :)

Кстати, индексы все ли нужные созданы, чтобы нормально джойнилось, и план выполнения смотрели?

Comment: индексы все есть, план смотрел, пишет нужно добавить work_mem, добавил, но вроде прироста особого не заметил, очень долгое сканирование индекса получается Seq Scan

Answer (score 0):

Вы стартуете от таблицы `a` и все тормоз из-за `join`. Поиграться бы, но генерить 400 лямов строк не охота..
При индексе по полям `col_table_a_id`, `id` в таблице `b` попробуйте:

```
select a.*, b.*
from(
  select row_number()over(partition by col_table_a_id order by id)rn,*
  from b
)b
  join a.id = b.col_table_a_id 
where b.rn=1
```

Неуверен что оптимизатор постгреса сделает с row_number, можно ещё попробовать с группировкой

```
select a.*, b.*
from(
  select min(id)id, col_table_a_id 
  from b
  group by col_table_a_id 
)t 
  join a on a.id = t.col_table_a_id 
  join b on b.id = t.id
```

Попробуйте взять не 400 миллионов строк, а лимит, скажем, в 1 миллион в подзапросе на таблицу `b`.
Сможете спокойно поэкспериментировать с разными вариантами. Не жидая каждую попытку по 10+ минут.

пс: Специально не указал `limit`, т.к. вы не сказали порядок сортировки.

ппс: Сделать битовую метку не такая уж и плохая идея. При условии, что из таблицы `b` не будут удаляться записи.

пппс: А ещё можно хранить ссылку из таблички `a` на первую "свою" строку в табличке `b`

Comment: Если будут удаляться, можно триггер повесить на пересчёт )  Хотя это конечно не очень выглядит уже )

Comment: @CrazyElf триггер на удаление в табличке 400кк строк с поиском по неселективному полю и сортировкой в среднем по 40к записям... удачи :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашел быстрый способ и без особой заморочки, для этого нужно создать  materialized view, запросом выбираем все первые id и заполняем таблицу, дальше в самом запросе меняем таблицу на нашу вьюху и получаем скорость выборку от 500mc до 1 минуты в моем случаи, что на много быстрее чем было, я ждал 10минут и запрос не был завершен.

```
select "a".*, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from "a"
   inner join b_view as b on b.col_table_a_id = a.id 
limit 100 offset 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Может что-то типа такого

```
SELECT 
  "a".*, 
  b.col1, 
  b.col2, 
  b.col3 
FROM 
  "a" 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      b.col_table_a_id, 
      b.col1, 
      b.col2, 
      b.col3 
    FROM 
      b 
    WHERE 
      a.id = b.col_table_b_id 
    LIMIT 
      100
  ) bb ON bb.col_table_a_id = a.id
```

Comment: Вы сами знаете какой будет результат, я написал, в таблице "Б" более 400 миллионов, вы мне предлагаете из этой таблице вытащить всего 100?